# How to search for videos using keyword within specific list of channels / channel ids given - youtube data API v3?

Tags: youtube-api

How to search for videos within a specific list of channels/channel ids given - youtube data API v3

I have tried to search for videos within a channel by specifying channelId, is there a way to give more than one channelId as comma-separated values or list

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=relevance&q=object%20oriented&key=your_key&channelId=UCcabW7890RKJzL968QWEykA

Answer (score 0):

No, the channelID parameter accepts a single ID. Each channel call must be separate.